# Django TypeError, invite users to 'team'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want to signed in user to be able to invite users to a 'team', where the teams they can select from are only those they are a part of. I keep getting the same error (**init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user') when I try and output a list of all teams in model UserTeams where the userID = current logged in user.

My view:

```
def invite(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = InvitePlayerForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        userteam = form.save(commit=False)
        userteam.save()

else:
    form = InvitePlayerForm()
    query = UserTeams.objects.all()
return render(request, 'teammanager/invite.html', {
    "invite": query,
    "form": form
})
```

My Form:

```
    class InvitePlayerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta: 
        model = UserTeams
        fields = ['userID','teamID']

     def __init__(self,user,*args,**kwargs):
        super (InvitePlayerForm,self ).__init__(user,*args,**kwargs) 
        self.fields['teamID'].queryset = Team.objects.filter(id__in = 
UserTeams.objects.filter(userID = user))
```

My UserTeams model:

```
class UserTeams(models.Model):
    userID = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teamID = models.ForeignKey(Team,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My HTML:

```
<html>

<body>

        <h4>Invite players to your team</h4>

<form method="post">

{% csrf_token %}

{{ form.as_p }}

<input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Add Player"></button>


</form>
```

Comment: Please add the error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

You've redefined the signature of the form so that it accepts a `user` element. But you haven't actually passed that user when you create the form. How else are you expecting it to get into the form?

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = InvitePlayerForm(request.user, request.POST)
    ...
else:
    form = InvitePlayerForm(request.user)
```

(Note also, your queryset would be better as `Team.objects.filter(userteam__UserId=user`.)

Comment: I'm now getting this error: 'FieldError at /invite/
Cannot resolve keyword 'userteam' into field'